# Full Size of Index in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any way to know the size of index programmatically .Right now I am trying URL  "http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?h=index,store.size"

which give size upto one decimal (For eg it gives 2.6 for both 2.60 and 2.66). I want size upto two decimal.Kindly suggest some points.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the *one* single extra digit gain you?

Comment: I am trying to figure out when data gets fully  loaded .So I am reading the web response and according watching if size changes over 10 sec .So if it will not provide me size upto 2 decimal ,When size will be in GB(eg 3.40 gb it will take more time to become 3.5). and in mean time it will show data got loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way to achieve what you need is to ask for the [size in bytes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat.html#numeric-formats), so you have full precision, simply append `...&bytes=b` at the end of your URL, like this:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?h=index,store.size&bytes=b'
```

You'll get a response like this:

```
index1       37224042277 
index2        5864821948 
index3        6964380398
```

Comment: @Rajeev You can use the checkmark next to this answer to indicate that it solved your problem if you like.